# Will carpenter bee larvae die if trapped or find a way to bore out?

Tags: entomology, behaviour, bees

I had a carpenter bee problem last year, beginning with the awful sounds the larvae make! The exterminators couldn’t find the bore holes (they were/are inside a gap between top of the foundation and sub floor of what was once a garage).  I eventually hired a contractor, who removed the vinyl siding, and discovered a straight line drill hole up the plywood!  He replaced plywood and insulation, saw no other evidence (except two dead bees), and sealed up the gap. It’s now spring, and I am hearing them once again.  My fear is that there is a gallery in a floor joist. If there ARE larvae and they ARE there, will they eventually just emerge into that now sealed up gap and die, or bore their way through where it was sealed or, worse yet ~ my floor?  Thank you.